# help(iface.activeLayer.startEditing) question

Tags: qgis, python, arcpy, pyqgis, qgis-3

Beginner here.
I am trying to find out what classes some methods are associated with and what those methods do by using the help function for some code im working on as seen below

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
```

I have already used help(iface.activeLayer) and that works
But I am having issue when I try `help(iface.startEditing)` or `help(iface.activeLayer.startEditing)`

I am really just trying to figure out where the `startEditing()` method is coming from/ what class it is apart of. Also, is there a python code that returns the class a method is apart of.

Comment: I would recommend you check out https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html . Which will help you get an understanding of the pyqgis api. You can also checkout the actual api at https://api.qgis.org/api/index.html

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no a method returning the class of a method in Python.

You may want to use `Search` in QGIS API Documentation ([C++ API](https://api.qgis.org/api/index.html), [Python API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/)). If you type a method name in Search box, you get a list of classes which have the method.

[image]

[image]

And use `help(layer.startEditing)` to get help on `startEditing`. Also use, for example, `dir(layer)` or `dir(QgsVectorLayer)` to get what methods and properties `layer` instance or `QgsVectorLayer` class have.

Answer (score 5):

Additional to @Kadir Şahbaz: you can use the `type()` statement:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
print(type(layer))
```

which will print: <class 'qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer'>. Since startEditing is a method, you see the class to which this method belongs....hope this helps